# Time period for analysing an instantaneous sound wave and then converting it to the frequency domain?

Tags: digital-communications, sound, fourier

I am confused about how a signal is analysed in the frequency domain after being recorded in the time domain instantly.

Does the spectrum of frequencies that are displayed based on a previous period, maybe 1 second? Therefor you have a continuous signal, at least 1 second of it and you can then Fourier transform it to the frequency domain?

If this is not the case, how can you break an instantaneous continuous signal that you are recording into a frequency spectrum instantly?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a recording of a signal X. The recording duration is T. If you calculate the discrete Fourier transform of the recording it has spectrum components at frequencies 0, 1/T, 2/T, 3/T etc...

To stay in truth actually the common complex number discrete Fourier transform formalism generates also components to frequencies -1/T, -2/T, -3/T etc... That's because using complex numbers all important math formulas get unbelievable simplicity and symmetry when compared to case where only positive frequencies are used.

Its useless to go to higher frequencies than a half of the sample rate, because to have somehow meaningful non-aliased samples the signal X must be band-limited to lower frequencies than a half of the sample rate. In an audio  recorder which has sample rate = 44.1kHz all audio at 22.05kHz and above must be killed to avoid audible aliasing noises. To ensure it the recorder must have a low pass filter at the input of the AD-converter.

The calculated spectrum components at frequencies 0, 1/T, 2/T etc... are actually a fully covering sample set of the continuous spectrum of the time limited signal portion just like the recorded samples can cover fully the recorded original continuous time domain signal if the signal is band limited. One can reconstruct the recording from the spectrum samples by doing the inverse discrete Fourier transform ie. by summing the calculated sinewaves.

The recorded portion to be Fourier transformed is generally in practical systems windowed smoothly i.e. the input volume is turned ON gradually in the beginning and it's also turned OFF gradually in the end. That's because sharp beginning and ending introduce unwanted spectrum components which distort what's the original spectrum of X. Unfortunately smooth start and end also remove some information, but mathematicians have developed different smooth windowing curves for different compromises how much the spectrum is distorted.

Windowing is presented in digital signal processing books as thoroughly as discrete Fourier transforms and how they are calculated effectively with FFT-algorithms. This Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function shows the most popular smooth windowings and what benefits one can get with them when compared to abrupt starting and stopping the recording (=using the rectangular windowing).

Answer (score 0):

User287001 beat me to it.

I'll leave this here as another reference regarding windowing:
https://download.ni.com/evaluation/pxi/Understanding%20FFTs%20and%20Windowing.pdf

Comment: That's a well-written tutorial and it does NOT tease practical workers with the equations nor negative frequencies of the common complex number formalism. A good insert!